# for loop into map method with Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I want to use a "for" into a map method in scala.

How can I do it?

For example here for each line read I want to generate a random word :

```
val rdd = file.map(line => (line,{
            val chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            val word = new String;
            val res = new String;
            val rnd = new Random;
            val len = 4 + rnd.nextInt((6-4)+1);

            for(i <- 1 to len){
                val char = chars(rnd.nextInt(51));
                word.concat(char.toString);
            }

            word;
}))
```

My current output is :

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array((1,""), (2,""), (3,""), (4,""), (5,""), (6,""), (7,""), (8,""), (9,""), (10,""), (11,""), (12,""), (13,""), (14,""), (15,""), (16,""), (17,""), (18,""), (19,""), (20,""), (21,""), (22,""), (23,""), (24,""), (25,""), (26,""), (27,""), (28,""), (29,""), (30,""), (31,""), (32,""), (33,""), (34,""), (35,""), (36,""), (37,""), (38,""), (39,""), (40,""), (41,""), (42,""), (43,""), (44,""), (45,""), (46,""), (47,""), (48,""), (49,""), (50,""), (51,""), (52,""), (53,""), (54,""), (55,""), (56,""), (57,""), (58,""), (59,""), (60,""), (61,""), (62,""), (63,""), (64,""), (65,""), (66,""), (67,""), (68,""), (69,""), (70,""), (71,""), (72,""), (73,""), (74,""), (75,""), (76,""), (77,""), (78,""), (79,""), (80,""), (81,""), (82,""), (83,""), (84,""), (85,""), (86...
```

I don't know why the right side is empty.

Comment: I have the same problem but in my case i already declared them as var but still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word.concat` doesn't modify `word` but return a new String, you can make `word` a variable and add new string to it:

```
var word = new String
....
for {
    ...
    word += char
    ...
}
```

Comment: when I try it i receive this error error: value += is not a member of String
word += char.toString

Comment: You need to declare `word` as a variable. Notice the `var` keyword in front of `word` instead of `val` which is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for `var` here. It's a one liner

```
  Seq.fill(len)(chars(rnd.nextInt(51))).mkString
```

This will create a sequence of Char of length `len` by repeatedly calling `chars(rnd.nextInt(51))`, then makes it into a String.

Thus you'll get something like this :

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.util.Random

val chars = ('a' to 'z') ++ ('A' to 'Z')

val rdd = file.map(line => {
  val randomWord = {
    val rnd = new Random
    val len = 4 + rnd.nextInt((6 - 4) + 1)
    Seq.fill(len)(chars(rnd.nextInt(chars.length-1))).mkString
  }
  (line, randomWord)
})
```

Comment: I've took the liberty to update your answer if you don't mind. :)

Comment: If you like. I thought it was fairly clear already :) I tweaked it still further